# How to use variable value in for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, range, syntax-error

Im trying to use a variable value in the range() in for loop as shown in the below code

```
n = int((length + 15) / 16); n is being calculated and typecasted to int
for j in range(n)
```

For which im getting sytax error.
could anyone tell how exactly to solve this

Comment: please post the full code snippet so we can reproduce the problem, and the error message

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Python Comments starts with a #, and Python will ignore them:

```
# this is comment
print('something')
```

Comments can be placed at the end of a line, and Python will ignore the rest of the line:

```
print("Hello, World!") #This is a comment
```

so your code should be:

```
n = int((length + 15) / 16) # n is being calculated and typecasted to int
for j in range(n):
    # continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int((length + 15) / 16); n is being calculated and typecasted to int
```

The above line is not valid python. The comment you made needs to have `#` and not `;` suffix to let python know the following part is a comment. So by replacing `;` with `#`, you code becomes syntactically valid.

```
n = int((length + 15) / 16) # n is being calculated and typecasted to int
```

The above line is.